# Is there a way to reference the root development folder in MSBuild or Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Visual Studio has wonderful macros (terrible name for a variable) for things like $SolutionDir and $ProjectDir but I cannot find anything that points to my root development folder.  I understand that this is a nebulous concept in some cases but it would sure be helpful to have a way to reference my root .git checkout folder so I don't have to use relative paths that break when things get moved around.  Is anyone aware of a way to derive this in Visual Studio that I might be missing?  I could write an extension for it but I'd ideally like a means that works in Visual Studio and MSBuild (for Azure DevOps) so I don't have to develop two solutions.

Comment: You should define what 'root development' folder means to you.

Comment: I thought I did when I said: "it would sure be helpful to have a way to reference my root .git checkout folder"

Comment: Depends on the content. Does that mean *all* your project files are in there, and the logic you're after = 'starting from current project file, start traversing parent directories and lookup the last one where a .git subdirectory is found'? Or if the first one sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using [property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ​<ProjectRootDir>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory), '.git/index'))</ProjectRootDir>
​</PropertyGroup>
```

This should work from within any level of directory inside your folder structure (that is inside any MSBuild file therein), as long as you only have `.git\index` once in your folder structure (at your definition of "top most" level).

Comment: Christian, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!